# How can I gain more control over my API controller routing in MVC Core?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

In old Web API 2 we used to set up routing in WebApi.config like this:

```
Map(routes, "MyNamedRoute", "{controller}/custom/preview",
            new {action = "PreviewSomthing"});
```

So the route would go to the Controller named in the first segment of the URL and then to the PreviewSomething action or without a default action then a method name matching the HTTP verb or a method with an attribute matching the HTTP verb of the request.

Now in ASP.Net MVC Core, everyone seems to be using:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

for plain MVC type routes mixed with attribute routing for Web API controllers.

Is this now considered the best practice?
I'd prefer more control actually defining my routes.  It seems like they would be more testable that way.  Unless there is still a routes collection object somewhere we can still access to test routes.

In this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing
there is a section called: "Using Routing Middleware".

You need:

```
services.AddRouting()
```

in configure of startup.cs

Here is the example they give:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var trackPackageRouteHandler = new RouteHandler(context =>
    {
        var routeValues = context.GetRouteData().Values;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(
            $"Hello! Route values: {string.Join(", ", routeValues)}");
    });

    var routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder(app, trackPackageRouteHandler);

    routeBuilder.MapRoute(
        "Track Package Route",
        "package/{operation:regex(^track|create|detonate$)}/{id:int}");

    routeBuilder.MapGet("hello/{name}", context =>
    {
        var name = context.GetRouteValue("name");
        // This is the route handler when HTTP GET "hello/<anything>"  matches
        // To match HTTP GET "hello/<anything>/<anything>,
        // use routeBuilder.MapGet("hello/{*name}"
        return context.Response.WriteAsync($"Hi, {name}!");
    });

    var routes = routeBuilder.Build();
    app.UseRouter(routes);
}
```

This example is really to complex and abstract to be useful to me.
But it is supposed to support methods like:
MapGet
and
MapPost

Is attribute routing the more accepted way now?
Is it the most standard way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the general recommendation is to use attribute routes for WebAPIs. However you can totally use the MVC style routes if that is your preference. The difference between the two techniques you are highlighting is just a new shorthand syntax

When you type

```
"{Controller=Foo}/..."
```

You just specify the default value.

The new system is actually a lot more flexible then the WebAPI2, and you can build a lot more complex schemes if you choose to. If you don't have a strong reason, you probably want to go with the built in support.

Last instead of iterating over a list of routes like MVC and WebAPI did, there is now a much more efficient tree structured routing algorithm, that makes routing a LOT cheaper when the number of routes is large (logN instead of N). You will note the signature of UseMVC exposes a routebuilder instead of a routecollection, in an effort to abstract the actual underlying runtime routing mechanism from the configuration time.

Here are a few samples of advanced/custom routing:

[Using Action Constraints](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.ActionConstraintSample.Web)

[Custom routing conventions](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.CustomRoutingConvention)

[Custom routing sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.CustomRouteSample.Web)

Last a complete redo of of how MVC works Nancy style, side by side with existing routing. I wouldn't take this as a recommendation, but more of a way to show the flexibility of the system and how far it can take you.

[Nancy style routing inside MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.Modules)